# Comparison of two String is not working in script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually in my function I have to compare two strings, the one string I fetch through the db and compare to the `null` string but it's not working..
Here is my Code:

```
   order.items.forEach(function(entry) {
                            result += '<tr>' 
                                      + '<td>'+'<font size=2>'+ a++ + '</font>'+ '</td>'
                                      + '<td>' +'<font size=2>'+ entry.title + '</font>'+ '</td>'
                                      + '<td>' +'<font size=2>'+ entry.quantity + '</font>'+'</td>'        
                                    if(entry.personalization == 'null')     //here is the problem                                                       
                                      + '<td>' +'<font size=2>'+ 'No Personalization' + '</font>'+'</td>'
                                    else
                                      + '<td>' +'<font size=2>'+ entry.personalization + '</font>'+'</td>'                                          


                                    + '</tr>';
                        })

                     result +='</table>';

$('.modal-body').html(result);
```

Comment: `null` not `'null'`

Comment: compare it like if(!(entry.personalization))

Comment: @Ripun What if `entry.personalization` is set to zero? Will your tip still hold?

Comment: @spender he is assuming the entry.personalization as null value when checking so if it is set to 0 then there is no meaning on checking for null isn't it ?

Comment: Can you tell us what the value of `typeof entry.personalization` is?

Comment: and console.log(entry.personalization)

Comment: @Dhruv can you please see what console.log(entry.personalization) is returning ?

Comment: @DhruvTyagi , Please try by using - if(entry.personalization === "")

Comment: @Ripun on console its show null value(undefined) and when i am casting into the string, still problem remain same

Comment: @DhruvTyagi try if(entry.personalization == 'undefined')

Answer (score 2):

Use `console.log(entry.personalization)` to check value.

Dhara's answer should work...

I also use it for null check.

```
(!entry.personalization)
```

or try

```
(entry.personalization != "")
```

Answer (score 1):

To check empty or null string in jquery:

```
if (!entry.personalization) {
    // is empty
}
```

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla $.trim() is used for Remove the white spaces at the start and at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in your question, if one string i fetched by you and the other string is **"null"**, It is a clear question of string comparison and not checking null...

Javascript has localeCompare() method to compare strings..

You should use

```
entry.personalization.localeCompare("null");
```

or its inverse

```
var n = "null";
n.localeCompare(entry.personalization);
```

this function returns boolean.

Comment: what does it return console.log(entry.personalization)

Comment: actually i dont know how to use console.log() so i will update the result soon

Comment: no problem... let me tell you.... console.log() is a function which will log the values inside the console... If you want to see it, press F-12 on your keyboard with a browser open and go to its console tab... you will see the value of console.log() in it...

Comment: that means your entry.personalization holds null.. and not "null"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114935/discussion-between-tirthraj-barot-and-dhruv-tyagi).

Comment: now m casting the null value into the string but still is not work
 if (typeof (entry.personalization) != 'undefined'){

Comment: Please discuss it in chat.. @DhruvTyagi

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap `null` around `''`.

Simply use :-

```
if(entry.personalization == null)
```